# Prisma create connection in an explizit many to many relationship

Tags: javascript, mysql, postgresql, prisma

I have the following schema where my goal is:
When I update the user by connecting the User with an existing "Abschnitt", I want to add all "Aufgaben" in this connecting "Abschnitt" to the explicit AufgabenOnUser Table.

When executing the explained query following preconditions are given:

- The User exists
- The Abschnitt exists
- The multiple Aufgaben exists and the one to many Relation between Abschnitt and Aufgaben exists

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}


model User {
  id          Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  email       String        @unique
  pwd         String
  rolle       Role          @default(USER)
  abschnitte  Abschnitt[]
  aufgaben    AufgabenOnUser[]
}


model Abschnitt {
  id            Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  titel         String    @db.VarChar(255) @unique
  beschreibung  String    @db.Text
  kosten        Int       
  besitzer      User[]
  aufgaben      Aufgabe[]
}

model Aufgabe {
  id            Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  titel         String      @db.VarChar(255)
  beschreibung  String      @db.Text
  abschnittID   Int         
  abschnitt     Abschnitt   @relation(fields: [abschnittID], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  nutzer        AufgabenOnUser[]
}

model AufgabenOnUser {
  aufgabe       Aufgabe           @relation(fields: [aufgabeId], references: [id])
  aufgabeId     Int
  user          User              @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId        Int
  status        AufgabenStatus    @default(NICHTGEPLANT)
  kommentar     String            @db.Text
  geplant       DateTime?
  
  @@id([aufgabeId, userId])  
}


enum Role {
  USER
  ADMIN
  FACHPERSON
}

enum AufgabenStatus {
  ERLEDIGT
  GEPLANT
  NICHTGEPLANT
}
```

My approach is something like this:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { disconnect } from 'process'


const prisma = new PrismaClient()


async function main() {

    await prisma.user.deleteMany()
    await prisma.abschnitt.deleteMany()
    await prisma.aufgabe.deleteMany()

    // Create Data to work on. In production db already filled => variables users, deutsch 
    // and mathe would not be in scope...

    const users = await prisma.user.createMany({
        data: [{
            email: "random1@rnd.rnd",
            pwd: "123"
        },{
            email: "random2@rnd.rnd",
            pwd: "123"
        },{
            email: "random3@rnd.rnd",
            pwd: "123"
        },]
    })

    const deutsch = await prisma.abschnitt.create({
        data: {
            titel: "Deutsch",
            beschreibung: "Lerne Deutsch",
            kosten: 200,
            aufgaben: {
                createMany: {
                    data: [{
                        titel: "Lesen",
                        beschreibung: "Lese Deutsch"
                    },{
                        titel: "Schreiben",
                        beschreibung: "Schreibe Deutsch"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    })

    const mathe =  await prisma.abschnitt.create({
        data: {
            titel: "Mathe",
            beschreibung: "Lerne Mathe",
            kosten: 200,
            aufgaben: {
                createMany: {
                    data: [{
                        titel: "Addition",
                        beschreibung: "Lerne Addition"
                    },{
                        titel: "Multiplikation",
                        beschreibung: "Lerne Multiplikation"
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    })

   // Here I try to solve the explained problem

    const data = await prisma.user.update({
        where: {
            email: "random1@rnd.rnd"
        },
        data: {
            abschnitte: {
                connect: {
                    titel: "Mathe"
                }
            },
            // aufgaben: include all existing Aufgaben in relation with Mathe 
        },
        include: {
            abschnitte: {
                include: {
                    aufgaben: true
                }
            },
            aufgaben: true
        }
    })

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
}


main()

  .then(async () => {

    await prisma.$disconnect()

  })

  .catch(async (e) => {

    console.error(e)

    await prisma.$disconnect()

    process.exit(1)

  })
```

Hope someone can help. If you have another approach for the schema which would make querying easier I'm open to it.

Comment: what is an explicit many to many relationship. a many to many relationship is represented by a bridge table, where you add the linking ids together. for example you would save user A with shores D (which are linked to single must dos)

Comment: Related to the docs of prisma 
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations
Prisma makes a difference between expicit and implicit. Where in an explicit many to many relationship makes it possible by adding additional info to the relationship.In my example between User and Aufgaben I am storing [status, kommentar, geplant]. Therefore I had to create an extra linking table in the schema. In an implicit many to many relationship prisma does all the linking in sql for you. I have an implicit between Abschnitt and User

Comment: It depends onhow your model works, if the user can select Abschnitte(shores) and then has to do all Aufgaben(Todos) of that shore, you make a relation ship beteen userpnAbschnitt and AbschnittonAufgabe, if a user gas only to make some of the Aufgaben(Todos) you keeo your AufgabenOnUser  and Add on For AbschnittONAufgave, so that you can get all Aabschnittethat beliong to the aufgaben